# Adress of pointer to an array giving warning when assigned without '&'

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
 {
   int (*p_arr)[10];
   int (*ptr)[10];
   int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
   ptr = &arr;
   p_arr = arr;
}
```

When compiling it gives an error

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Why is using just the name of array gives this warning wheras name of array and address of array are meant to be same ?

Comment: GCC version gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the type of `&arr` is `int (*) []` (pointer to array of int), not `int *[]` (array of pointers to int).

Comment: @Virgile oh d**n! I wonder if I'm blind or stupid...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
ptr = &arr;
```

**L.H.S** is `int(*)[]` and **R.H.S** is `int(*)[]` too. Hence no issue.

Now let us examine

```
p_arr = arr
```

**L.H.S** is `int(*)[]` and **R.H.S** is `int[]` .
Therefore,the warning as `assignment from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: but isn't &arr same as arr usually ?

Comment: NO they aren't. `arr` is similar to `&arr[0]` i.e. pointer to the first element of the array. `&arr` means pointer to the array.

Answer (score 3):

For

```
 ptr = &arr;
```

both have type `int(*)[]` which are compatible.

For case

```
 p_arr = arr;
```

here `arr` has type `int[10]` which is not compatible with type of `p_arr` (`int(*)[10]`).

Also

> ```
> wheras name of array and address of array are meant to be same ?
> ```

No. `arr` (The name of an array decays to a pointer to the first element) and `&arr` not implies same. `arr` is similer to `&arr[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Name of array is pointer to its first element, which is a integer not the pointer to whole array.